# Can not format my USB drive through diskpart

Tags: windows-7, usb

Recently I am having problems with my USB drive which can't be formatted, Even though I tried disk part and it recognized and showed my 14 GB flash drive on the list still I get:

```
DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ### Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          111 GB  1024 KB

  Disk 1    Online           14 GB      0 B

DISKPART> select disk 1

Disk 1 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> clean

DiskPart has encountered an error: The system cannot find the file specified.
See the System Event Log for more information.

DISKPART>
```

Comment: Did you look at the system event log? Control Panel>Administrative tools>event viewer

Comment: Yes I looked through everything and done the process multiple times but couldn't find anything useful

Comment: There is a log created with details of the error. Most of the time this is a disk I/O error, it cannot read/write to the drive, but until you find the log it is a Guess.